# How to return variable from FileRead

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, file-read

I would like to return the JSON data from the data method. How would I go about doing this? I attempted to implement a promise without success.

```
function data() {
    fs.readFile('./test.json', (err, data)  => {
        let json = JSON.parse(data);
    });
};
```

`Alternative Solution:`

```
const json = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./test.json'));
```

Comment: You have any error message from here?
if you put a console.log(json) just before the declaration of it, what does it show?

Comment: Post has been updated accordingly.

Comment: dont put the console.log outside the readfile, but inside of it

Comment: I want to return the variable `json` from the data method. If I console.log from inside of the fileread block, it will log - but I would like to return it from the data method.

Comment: I just wanted to know if you have any error as i didnt understand if you were having any.
If not, you can use async/await and it will work just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can just require the json file without needing to read it with fs.

```js
const json = require('./test.json')
```